# jQuery not hiding element before handler returns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that executes when a user clicks on a button. The first thing I want to do is hide the button and then run a function that takes a long time to run. The problem is that the button gets hidden only after the blocking function runs. There's a jsFiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g77Lyysp/) and here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Test').click(function () {

        $(this).hide();
        console.log('button should be hidden');

        LotsOfWork();
    });

});

function LotsOfWork() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
}
```

As you can see in the Fiddle, the console shows the string but the button is still visible and only gets hidden after `LotsOfWork()` is done.

How can I change this so that the button gets hidden first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a common issue, when you call hide() before the browser renders the changes applied to the DOM you have to wait for it to complete the js execution.

One solution is to use a `setTimeout(myfunc,0);` to delay the call of your slow function to the next cycle.
In this way the browser have the time to complete js execution, render the changes and execute your function on the next iteration.

```
    $('#Test').click(function () {

        $(this).hide();
        console.log('button should be hidden');

        setTimeout(LotsOfWork, 0);
    });
```

Another solution is to use JQuery callback to handle it.

Comment: Yes, but It should not be the game of spot the difference.

Comment: It also take time to hide

Comment: Please explain why downvoting

Comment: this is a workaround, it's better to use "complete" option of .hide() function that I wrote above.

Comment: Yes but your answer it's only usable with jQuery mine it's plain vanilla js.

Comment: so you should write hide function with vanilla js, such as scope using jQuery is not a problem. You are still making it with a workaround and you can't guarantee that your solution will work in future.

Answer (score 2):

Use default callback in jquery it hides the button quickly and after callback the function LotsOfWork

```
 $(this).hide('fast', function() { LotsOfWork() });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g77Lyysp/1/)

Comment: Maybe you can explain it to the user what you have done so that he fully understands it

Comment: That hides it fast but I want it hidden now! Even with 0 as the parameter, it still takes time.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean hidden

Answer (score 0):

You should use .hiddens() "complete" option for this. Here I updated your code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Test').click(function () {
        $(this).hide({
            complete: function () {
                LotsOfWork();
            }
        });
        console.log('button should be hidden');
    });
});

function LotsOfWork() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g77Lyysp/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could use .on() instead of click. This will allow you to manipulate dynamically generated elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$('#Test').on('click', function() {
       $(this).hide();
       LotsOfWork();
    });
});

function LotsOfWork() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
}
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g77Lyysp/6/ - I've used setTimeout instead of a for loop to demonstrate lag between click and alert.